# crossOrigin issue with Chrome using the gifshot library

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

I want to use the *gifshot* library to capture a video to GIF. However, when I try with this code:

```
gifshot.createGIF({
    'video': ['video.mp4']
    },
    function(obj) {
      if(!obj.error) {
        var image = obj.image,
        animatedImage = document.createElement('img');
        animatedImage.src = image;
        document.body.appendChild(animatedImage);
    }
});
```

the code works perfectly fine with Firefox but not with Chrome. In Chrome I get:

> Failed to load because no supported source was found.

in the console. I noticed that the problem came from `crossorigin = "Anonymous"` when the library created the video tag with this attribute.

Comment: Suggest you check the repo issue tracker for that library for known issues

Comment: i dont need issue tracker i know the probleme, but i dont know solution, the probleme is crossorigin = "Anonymous" dont work for chrome

Comment: that doesn't explain why or potential fix which might be found in issue tracker